# What's the best way to send images between users, and keep it in a server for a time in Android?

Tags: android

My application requires sending images between users, and sometimes these images may be consulted by other users ..

What is the best way to be sent or stored on the server? I have read can be uploaded to an FTP server and I have also read that they can be converted to a string in BASE64 and save the string in my MySQL Database .. and to display them they would have to be decoded.

What do you recommend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a topic of great debate on the internet (even here on stackoverflow), check this URL:

http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525

The main conclusion is that if size of your image is less than certain size ( 200 KB i guess, not sure as i had read it a while back ), then its faster to read images from database, otherwise you should go with file system and just store the path and name combination of the image resource in database. Plus the file system approach is more scalable as well. Most large organizations prefer the file system approach.

Hope that helps ...